# Have the server interpret www.example.com/directory as a directory rather than a Drupal path

Tags: 6, path-aliases

I've got a Drupal 6 site running at webroot, and a MediaWiki wiki running at webroot/wiki. I can access the wiki fine by going to wiki.webroot, but when I try to access it using the path webroot/wiki the server interprets this as a Drupal 6 path: how do I get the server to interpret this as a directory? I'm guessing this is something to do with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

So, your drupal site lives at webroot, and your wiki lives at webroot/wiki? First thing i would suggest is to put your wiki outside your drupal root and creating a separate virtual host. You're asking for trouble with your current setup.

The .htaccess file that ships with Drupal *should* properly be treating webroot/wiki as a directory, if it exists. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879029/dont-understand-rewritecond-request-filename-f-and-d

If it just won't work for you, update Drupal's .htaccess to explicitly add your wiki path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wiki
```

Put this right before:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your rewrite section will look like this (comments elided):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wiki
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```